# calling functions in for loop - python

Tags: python, function

i have a lab for my computer science class and i can't seem to get it right.
we're required to import everything from math and to define functions for geometric shapes

ex:

```
def triangleArea(b,h):
    return b * h / 2
```

for calling it, we need to make a menu to make the user choose what they want for these geometric shapes. for example, if you chose the number 2 and it gives you the volume of a cylinder.

i just can't seem to understand how you call the function inside the while/for loops.

thank uu~!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def find_area(width, height): # define function
    return width * height

for i in range(10):
    area = find_area(i, 10) #calls function 'find_area()' and saves returned 
                            #value to variable area
    print(area) # prints area
count = 0
while count < 10:
    area = find_area(i, 10) #calls function 'find_area()' and save returned 
                            #value to variable area
    print(area)
    count += 1
```

Example calling function *find_area()* from within a for-loop and while-loop.